# Jenkinsfile Change Set Contains the Changed Files for the Remote Jenkinsfile Repository and Not the Repository I'm Trying to Build

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

So I'm trying to create a Jenkinsfile for moving developer code from git repos to the server they need to go to based on what branch the changes were merged into. So DEVEL branch changes get deployed to the DEVEL server and PROD to PROD etc. I need this file to be able to check which files are new, changed, removed and only work with those because each repo contains at least 20 files, up to hundreds and there are about ten repos and then multiply that for each server. This script will also be mostly copying files but it will also compile some PL/SQL and Pro*C and COBOL so this is why I would like to only work with the change set.

I also need to keep the Jenkinsfile on it's one repo for two reasons. To be able to reuse it for each new repo with minimal effort and to keep the developers for modifying it and bypassing certain checks and best practices for convenience sake.

The issue that I'm running into is that I cannot seem to produce a change set for the repo and branch. Whenever I try I just get the change set for the remote Jenkinsfile repository. I have seem some ways of doing this with the git diff-tool but considering I have many repositories for this file to apply to and they could change at any time it seems infeasible to hard code every single one of these git urls.

So far this is my remote Jenkinsfile that the plugin grabs and runs for each branch.

[image: Code snippet]

The output is everything is a successful checkout with the Jenkinsfile checked out first and then the repo. It process the logic and outputs "Changed files are: [Jenkinsfile]" which is the most recently changed file in the remote Jenkinsfile repo.

I was hoping for something like "Changed files are: [newFile, changedFile, removedFile]" which are the most recent changes in the repo branch I'm building.

Comment: Git *stores* snapshots (not changes), so to get changes out of Git you must take two snapshots and have something (e.g., `git diff`) compare the files *in* the two snapshots. What you'll see then depends on the two snapshots you picked. How you do that in Jenkins directly, I have no idea, but you'll definitely want to know which two snapshots Jenkins picked.

Comment: Ok that helps clear things up a touch about the snapshots. I'm still not sure how to implement it though. I know I can compare currentBuild and currentBuild.previousBuild but that would still just bring up the Jenkinsfile.